# Java: Finding the end of a string of text after a substring entered by the user, then replacing substring with new entered text

Tags: java, string, substring

This is what I need to do:

```
Enter a long string: The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
Enter a substring: jumped
Length of your string: 44
Length of your substring: 6
Starting position of your substring in string: 20
String before your substring: The quick brown fox
String after your substring:  over the lazy dog
Enter a position between 0 and 43: 18
The character at position 18 is x
Enter a replacement string: leaped
Your new string is: The quick brown fox leaped over the lazy dog
```

Below is what I have so far, including where I'm having trouble figuring out the "after" the substring portion and then with replacing the substring with a newly entered word:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Project02 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        // this asks the user to enter a string of text
        System.out.print("Enter a long string: ");
        String longer = keyboard.nextLine();        
        // this asks the user to enter a substring of the text previously entered
        System.out.print("Enter a substring: ");
        String substring = keyboard.nextLine();     
        // this prints out the length of the string and substring
        System.out.println("Length of your string: " + longer.length ());
        int lengthOfLonger = longer.length();
        System.out.println("Length of your substring: " + substring.length ());     
        // this returns the starting position of the given substring in the longer string
        int indexOfSubstring = longer.indexOf(substring);
        System.out.println("Starting position of your substring in string: " + (indexOfSubstring));
        // This returns the end position of the given substring in the longer substring
        String SubstringEnd = (substring + 1);
        //This returns the string of text before the beginning of the substring
        String before = longer.substring(0, indexOfSubstring);
        System.out.println("String before your substring: " + (before));
        // This returns the string of text after the end of the substring
        // need help here
        String after = longer.substring(SubstringEnd, + lengthOfLonger);
        System.out.println("String after your substring: " + after);    
        // This asks the user to enter a position between 0 and the end of the string
        System.out.print("Enter a position between 0 and " + (lengthOfLonger - 1) + ": ");
        int position = keyboard.nextInt();
        char letterPosition = longer.charAt(position);
        //This provides the character at the position entered by the user
        System.out.println("The character at position " + position + " is " + letterPosition);
        keyboard.nextLine();
        // This provides a replacement word for the substring
        System.out.print("Enter a replacement string: ");
        String newString = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Your new string is: " + before + newString + after);
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help on how to get that line of text after the substring. I may be able to figure out the last portion if I have that correct.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use the `replace` method for the last part?  `System.out.println("Your new string is: " + longer.replace(substring, newString));`  As a general principle, if you're going to use a class like `String`, it's a good idea to have a quick look at the Javadoc to see what useful methods it provides.

Comment: Thanks. Is that Javadoc you are describing the link Raspacorp gave me, or is it somewhere else? I haven't learned a lot of code yet, so sometimes I'm not even aware of what is available or where/how to look for it. Thanks.

Comment: OK, one of the best things you can do to improve your programming is to learn to use the Javadocs.  They tell you all about every class that comes with Java.  The link that Raspacorp gave is kind of the top level - from there, you need to click on String in the list on the lower left, to find out all about the methods of the String class.

Answer (score 0):

```
// this is the position of the end of your substring in the longer string
int endOfSubstring = indexOfSubstring + substring.length();
// this is the text from that point onwards in the longer string
String after = longer.substring(endOfSubstring);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I used Raspacorp's code and it worked. I appreciate you posting as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
    String mySubstring = "jumped";
    System.out.println(s.substring(s.indexOf(mySubstring)+ mySubstring.length()));
}
```

O/P :

```
over the lazy dog
```

What are we doing here ?.

```
s.indexOf(mySubstring)  --> gives index of first letter "j" of jumped.
s.indexOf(mySubstring) + mySubstring.length() --> add length of the string "jumped".
get substring from end of jumped i,e, from after "d" of jumped.
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry if I wasn't clear explaining. Raspacorp's answer helped. Thank you for commenting as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes in your code, I corrected it for you:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        // this asks the user to enter a string of text //
        System.out.print("Enter a long string: ");
        String longer = keyboard.nextLine();

        // this asks the user to enter a substring of the text previously entered //
        System.out.print("Enter a substring: ");
        String substring = keyboard.nextLine();

        // this prints out the length of the string and substring//
        System.out.println("Length of your string: " + longer.length ());
        int lengthOfLonger = longer.length();
        System.out.println("Length of your substring: " + substring.length ());

        //this returns the starting position of the given substring in the longer string//
        int indexOfSubstring = longer.indexOf(substring);
        System.out.println("Starting position of your substring in string: " + (indexOfSubstring) );


        //This returns the end position of the given substring in the longer substring//
        int substringEnd = ( indexOfSubstring + substring.length() );
        //This returns the string of text before the beginning of the substring//
        String before = longer.substring(0,indexOfSubstring);
        System.out.println("String before your substring: " + (before));

        //This returns the string of text after the end of the substring//
        String after = longer.substring(substringEnd, lengthOfLonger);
        System.out.println("String after your substring: " + after);

        //This asks the user to enter a position between 0 and the end of the string//
        System.out.print("Enter a position between 0 and " + (lengthOfLonger - 1) + ": ");
        int position = keyboard.nextInt();
        char letterPosition = longer.charAt(position);

        //This provides the character at the position entered by the user//
        System.out.println("The character at position " + position + " is " + letterPosition);
        keyboard.nextLine();

        //This provides a replacement word for the substring//
        System.out.print("Enter a replacement string: ");
        String newString = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Your new string is: " + before + newString + after);
    }
```

And this is a run of the program:

```
Enter a long string: I don’t know half of you half as well as I should like; and I like less than half of you half as well as you deserve.
Enter a substring: should like
Length of your string: 117
Length of your substring: 11
Starting position of your substring in string: 43
String before your substring: I don’t know half of you half as well as I 
String after your substring: ; and I like less than half of you half as well as you deserve.
Enter a position between 0 and 116: 43
The character at position 43 is s
Enter a replacement string: would like
Your new string is: I don’t know half of you half as well as I would like; and I like less than half of you half as well as you deserve.
```

The mistakes were these:

```
String SubstringEnd = (substring + 1 );
```

this should be an int and has to take the length of the substring and its position as shown in the corrected code.

```
String after = longer.substring(SubstringEnd, + lengthOfLonger);
```

This one had an invalid character "+"

I also renamed SubstringEnd to substringEnd for following java naming conventions.

**Disclaimer:** If this is a homework question, before posting this kind of questions you should read some java books, write lot of programs and I specially recommend the java API docs to understand java libraries: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Comment: Thank you! And this is a homework question. Unfortunately, the people that were supposed to be in the "Java help labs" have very limited hours (Like I'm in other classes during those hours) and this is my first time programming. We do have a book, but it's not really great at explaining things. I'm trying to read the Oracle docs as well, but I'm just not grasping it as well as I would like. If you have any other "newbie" books to recommend, I'd be grateful. Sometimes they just don't explain things to the level of "newbie" detail I need and make a lot of assumptions about what you know. Thanks!

Comment: Good books for starting with Java programming: Java in a Nutshell by David Flanagan; Java How to Program by Deitel and Deitel

Comment: @AshRo if you find this answer or any other solving your problem, you should mark it as accepted answer.